# Running Jersey Rest API without using container as jar

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Currently, I'm using Tomcat to keep my Backend along with my Rest API. When I want to use my Frontend, I'm just starting Tomcat, which holds the Backend-Project and then, I can access the the backend over the Rest-API using http-requests. 
Now I thought about getting rid of Tomcat and deploy it as a jar file, instead of a war file and run it locally via a Main method.
I've done it like that ([Source](https://yajdb.wordpress.com/2011/09/29/jersey-java-se-embedded-server-helloworld/)):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ResourceConfig config = new DefaultResourceConfig(RestApi.class);

        HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:8080/", config);

        server.start(); 
   }
```

An excerpt of my Rest-Class would be:

```
@Path("/schemas")
public class RestApi {

    @GET
    @Path("/hi")
    public String dropHi() {
        return "hi;
    }
}
```

Running this main works, but for some reason still can't access the Rest-Api. When I'm trying to get a "hi" by trying to reach `http://localhost:8080/api/schemas/hi` in the browser nothing happens. What could be wrong, does it even make sence what I'm trying to do? 
The idea is to run the backend later on a server without using Tomcat, just running it as a jar file and access it via the frontend, which you run locally on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it. There were two problems:

1. In my web.xml there was `<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>`, which wasn't used anymore so the link isn't `http://localhost:8080/api/schemas/hi`, but `http://localhost:8080/schemas/hi`.
2. In my web.xml I got the entry:

   ```
   <filter>
       <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
       <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
           <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE</param-value>
       </init-param>
   </filter>
   ```

   Not using a container anymore, I had to enable CORS another way. Finally I did it with the help of [this](http://crunchify.com/what-is-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-how-to-add-it-to-your-java-jersey-web-server/) like that:

   ```
   public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

       public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest req, ContainerResponse containerResponse) {

           ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.fromResponse(containerResponse.getResponse());

           // *(allow from all servers) OR http://example.com/
           responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

           // As a part of the response to a request, which HTTP methods can be used during the actual request.
           .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "API, CRUNCHIFYGET, GET, POST, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS")

           // How long the results of a request can be cached in a result    cache.
           .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "151200")

           // As part of the response to a request, which HTTP headers can be used during the actual request.
           .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with,Content-Type");

           String requestHeader = req.getHeaderValue("Access-Control-Request-Headers");

           if (null != requestHeader && !requestHeader.equals(null)) {
               responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", requestHeader);
           }

           containerResponse.setResponse(responseBuilder.build());
           return containerResponse;
       }
   }
   ```

   And set it in the Main method:

   ```
   config.getContainerResponseFilters().add(CORSFilter.class);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do makes sense. You want a *standalone* server and there is nothing wrong with that.

I did similar things, but with Jetty server and RESTEasy implementation of REST. Although I am not sure that everything will work out of the box for you (most probably not) it should still be very similar as both Jersey REST and RESTEasy are built according to the same specs: https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311

Anyways, here is what works for me:

```
//Obviously main method from which you start the server

public static void main(String[] consoleArgs) {
    final Server server= new Server(port);
    final HandlerList handlers= new HandlerList();
    addServlets(handlers);
    server.setHandler(handlers);
    server.start();
}

private static void addServlets(HandlerList handlers) {
    final ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler= new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
    handlers.addHandler(servletContextHandler);

    //handlers and servlets that I ommit...

    addRestServiceContainer(servletContextHandler);
}

// and here is the trick... 
// the settings you see here would normally go to web.xml file

private static void addRestServiceContainer(final ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler) {
    ServletHolder holder= new ServletHolder(new HttpServlet30Dispatcher());
    holder.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", "com.stackoverflow.rest.application.RestfulServiceContainer");
    holder.setInitParameter("resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix", "/rest");
    holder.setInitParameter("resteasy.providers", "org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider");
    servletContextHandler.addServlet(holder, RestResourcePaths.REST_SERVICES_BASE_PATH + "/*");
}
```

And as a final piece, here is how `com.stackoverflow.rest.application.RestfulServiceContainer` looks:

```
public class RestfulServiceContainer extends Application {

    private static final Set<Class<?>> fSingletons= new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    private static final Set<Object> fRestfulServices= new HashSet<Object>();

public RestfulServiceContainer() {
    registerServices();
    initProviders();
}

/**
 * Normally, when resteasy.scan is set to true all provider classes (with @Provider) are registered automatically,
 * but since this is a standalone Jetty app it doesn't work. So, we register provider classes here manually.
 */
private void initProviders() {
    fSingletons.add(TrafficInterceptor.class);
    fSingletons.add(LogInterceptor.class);
    fSingletons.add(RateLimitInterceptor.class);
    fSingletons.add(SecurityInterceptor.class);
    fSingletons.add(ExceptionHandler.class);
}

private void registerServices() {
    fRestfulServices.add(new GetWhateverService());
    fRestfulServices.add(new PostStuffService());
}

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    return fSingletons;
}

@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return fRestfulServices;
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, first of all. I think I figured something out: Chrome tells me "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.". When I was using Tomcat I have added CORS in the web.xml. So maybe that's the problem, I have to add CORS to my server settings somehow, could that be?

Comment: Like you did in `addRestServiceContainer()', mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: Exactly! Add it there